# Kubernetes Helm install stable/jenkins deprecation error calling Master.* values

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-helm

Hey trying to install jenkins on GKE cluster with this command

`helm install stable/jenkins -f test_values.yaml --name myjenkins`

My version of helm and kubectl if matters

```
helm version
Client: &version.Version{SemVer:"v2.13.0", GitCommit:"79d07943b03aea2b76c12644b4b54733bc5958d6", GitTreeState:"clean"}
Server: &version.Version{SemVer:"v2.13.0", GitCommit:"79d07943b03aea2b76c12644b4b54733bc5958d6", GitTreeState:"clean"}
```

```
kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"17", GitVersion:"v1.17.0", GitCommit:"70132b0f130acc0bed193d9ba59dd186f0e634cf", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-12-13T11:51:44Z", GoVersion:"go1.13.4", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"darwin/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"13+", GitVersion:"v1.13.11-gke.14", GitCommit:"56d89863d1033f9668ddd6e1c1aea81cd846ef88", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-11-07T19:12:22Z", GoVersion:"go1.12.11b4", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

Values downloaded with this command `helm inspect values stable/jenkins > test_values.yaml` and modified:

```
cat test_values.yaml
Master:
  adminPassword: 34LbGfq5LWEUgw // local testing
  resources:
    limits:
      cpu: '500m'
      memory: '1024'
  podLabels:
    nodePort: 32323
  serviceType: ClusterIp

Persistence:
  storageClass: 'managed-nfs-storage'
  size: 5Gi

rbac:
  create: true
```

and some weird new error after update

```
$ helm install stable/jekins --name myjenkins -f test_values.yaml
Error: failed to download "stable/jekins" (hint: running `helm repo update` may help)
$ helm repo update
Hang tight while we grab the latest from your chart repositories...
...Skip local chart repository
...Successfully got an update from the "stable" chart repository
Update Complete. ⎈ Happy Helming!⎈
$ helm install stable/jekins --name myjenkins -f test_values.yaml
Error: failed to download "stable/jekins" (hint: running `helm repo update` may help)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I can see you're trying to install `stable/jekins` which isn't in the helm repo instead of `stable/je`**n**`kins`. Please update your question if it's just misspelling and I'll update my answer , but I've tried your command:

```
$helm install stable/jekins --name myjenkins -f test_values.yaml
```

and got the same error:

```
Error: failed to download "stable/jekins" (hint: running `helm repo update` may help)
```

**EDIT** To solve next errors like:

```
Error: render error in "jenkins/templates/deprecation.yaml": template: jenkins/templates/deprecation.yaml:258:11: executing "jenkins/templates/deprecation.yaml" at <fail "Master.* values have been renamed, please check the documentation">: error calling fail: Master.* values have been renamed, please check the documentation
```

and

```
Error: render error in "jenkins/templates/deprecation.yaml": template: jenkins/templates/deprecation.yaml:354:10: executing "jenkins/templates/deprecation.yaml" at <fail "Persistence.* values have been renamed, please check the documentation">: error calling fail: Persistence.* values have been renamed, please check the documentation
```

and so on you also need to edit `test_values.yaml`

```
master:
  adminPassword: 34LbGfq5LWEUgw
  resources:
    limits:
      cpu: 500m
      memory: 1Gi
  podLabels:
    nodePort: 32323
  serviceType: ClusterIP

persistence:
  storageClass: 'managed-nfs-storage'
  size: 5Gi

rbac:
  create: true
```

And after that it's deployed successfully:

```
$helm install stable/jenkins --name myjenkins -f test_values.yaml
NAME:   myjenkins
LAST DEPLOYED: Wed Jan  8 15:14:51 2020
NAMESPACE: default
STATUS: DEPLOYED

RESOURCES:
==> v1/ConfigMap
NAME             AGE
myjenkins        1s
myjenkins-tests  1s

==> v1/Deployment
NAME       AGE
myjenkins  0s

==> v1/PersistentVolumeClaim
NAME       AGE
myjenkins  1s

==> v1/Pod(related)
NAME                        AGE
myjenkins-6c68c46b57-pm5gq  0s

==> v1/Role
NAME                       AGE
myjenkins-schedule-agents  1s

==> v1/RoleBinding
NAME                       AGE
myjenkins-schedule-agents  0s

==> v1/Secret
NAME       AGE
myjenkins  1s

==> v1/Service
NAME             AGE
myjenkins        0s
myjenkins-agent  0s

==> v1/ServiceAccount
NAME       AGE
myjenkins  1s


NOTES:
1. Get your 'admin' user password by running:
  printf $(kubectl get secret --namespace default myjenkins -o jsonpath="{.data.jenkins-admin-password}" | base64 --decode);echo
2. Get the Jenkins URL to visit by running these commands in the same shell:
  export POD_NAME=$(kubectl get pods --namespace default -l "app.kubernetes.io/component=jenkins-master" -l "app.kubernetes.io/instance=myjenkins" -o jsonpath="{.items[0].metadata.name}")
  echo http://127.0.0.1:8080
  kubectl --namespace default port-forward $POD_NAME 8080:8080

3. Login with the password from step 1 and the username: admin


For more information on running Jenkins on Kubernetes, visit:
https://cloud.google.com/solutions/jenkins-on-container-engine
```

Comment: yea it solved the issue, thanks, I had few typos in the yaml file

Answer (score 2):

The repo stable is going to be deprecated very soon and is not being updated. I suggest use jenkins chart from [Helm Hub](https://hub.helm.sh/charts/bitnami/jenkins)